# Post back a list of model in edit in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am displaying a list of items in a table in edit mode in a view. after editing the columns, i want to submit. But i am unable to postback the list. `List<Model>` shows null.

Comment: Can't help if we can't see what you've tried. Post your code.

Comment: @SaraCh: Don't expect your question to be answered if you can't show what you have already. Do something and then we will help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for you. I also had to display a list of items in a table, edit and post it back to the database. I don't know what your models look like because you did not post any code so I am going to use my own. Modify it to fit in with your scenario.

I'm going to make this sample very basic. Lets me just display a list of customers in a table with a check box next to each name to delete the customer or not.

My views are always strongly typed. I always pass in a view model to my view. I normally work with `IEnumberable` but I need the `Count` property on the view so I used `List` instead.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
     public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Your customer model could look something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller and action method could look something like this:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
     private readonly ICustomerRepository cusotmerRepository;

     public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository cusotmerRepository)
     {
          this.cusotmerRepository = cusotmerRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult List()
     {
          CustomerViewModel viewModel = new CustomerViewModel
          {
               Customers = customerRepository.GetAll()
          };
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult List(CustomerViewModel viewModel)
     {
          // Debug the incoming view model and then you will see that the list is there

          // Do whatever you need to do
     }
}
```

So now you have a list of customer objects, all that remains is the populating of the table.

Your view could look like this:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Customers.CustomerViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <table id="customers-datatable">
          <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Customers.Count(); i++)
               {
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                              @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers[i].FirstName)
                              @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Customers[i].FirstName)
                         </td>
                         <td>
                              @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers[i].LastName)
                              @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Customers[i].LastName)
                         </td>
                         <td>
                              @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Customers[i].IsDelete)
                              @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Customers[i].Id)
                         </td>
                    </tr>
               }

          </tbody>
     </table>
}
```

I've just added a check box to show you how to retain values from a table. You can modify it to include the text boxes.

I hope this helps.